# Change CBC path for pulp running on Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, linear-programming, pulp

so I'm trying to run a linear optimization on google colab using pulp library. However, when I run the solve function it return this error `PulpSolverError: Pulp: Error while executing /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pulp/apis/../solverdir/cbc/linux/64/cbc`.

When I check the path of the previously installed cbc solver using `which`, it returns this path `/usr/bin/cbc`. So it looks like it is a path problem.

Any clue on how to solve this? I'm using version 2.1 of pulp and version 2.9.9+repack1-1 of coinor-cbc. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify explicitly the CBC path. Example:

```
 prob.solve(pulp.COIN(path='/usr/bin/cbc'))
```